# Order of Beanstalkd jobs

Tags: php, queue, message-queue, beanstalkd

I have a beanstalkd jobs with only one worker.

First question: Are the jobs processed in the same order as they are puted in the tube?

Second: if I'll use multiple workers, how can I manage dependency between two jobs? Lets' say job1 and job2 can bu processed in the same time, but job3 has to be processed after job1.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific guarantee that jobs will be processed in the same order they are received, but its not unreasonable to assume that it will be the general case from the same tube - unless you are using different priorities.

As for how to ensure that a 'job3' is run after 'job1' or 'job2', if the only code that can create a job3, is at the end of job1 or 2 - that would solve that issue.